# Windows 11 laptop location country not updating for years at "home" network

Tags: windows, windows-11, geolocation

I moved few years ago. My laptop thinks i'm still at the old location which was another country while i'm at "home". My desktop at the same network shows the right address.
The problem is with chrome/ff/edge and with the maps app and bing and google maps.
I tried to click all kinds of location settings and i'm unable to reset windows location.
If i disable "Precise location" in windows setting it start showing my neighborhood.
I tried renaming my wifi and it didnt help either.

Comment: Did you take your wifi with you? Are both desktop & laptop using wifi, or is one wired? Do you live out in the middle of nowhere, or a big city?

Comment: Middle of nowhere. I took my router and now it's plugged as a second wifi point to another router. Wifi name is same as it was but "external" mac is different.

Comment: You'll probably have to wait until the mapping vans come by - more frequent in cities, of course. Of course, if you live too far from the nearest public road, they may never come close enough to recognise the device.

Comment: Try to: (1) Change the wifi SSID. (2) Turn off Location history in your google account. (3) Change the MAC address in the router's configuration.